# Ссылка на "Читать сообщение в приложении!"

Tags: предложение

Приветствую.
В мобильной версии (похорошела, кстати) есть бар с ссылкой на запуск приложения (например: `intent://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/194492/screenshot-определенной-части-экрана-средствами-html5#Intent;scheme=http;package=com.stackexchange.marvin;end`).
На мой взгляд это должна быть ссылка на приложение в маркете, а пиктограмма уже на запуск приложения. Или наоборот. Без приложения браузер ошибку кидает, что неприятно и ломает шаблон.
Идеалом было бы определение наличие приложения и вставку нужной ссылки, но `JS` этого не может (минус хорошего ограничения налицо).
Сначала я даже подумал что это баг, но, видимо, это фишка. Интересная, но маркетолог, наверное, не одобрил бы.